# Pandas row calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns and I am trying to use pandas to calculate it. I am a spreadsheet user lately learning python for fast calculation. I want to create a new column 'C' and I know only to use excel formulas but in python, I am aware of calculating the difference between two-row values. Not sure how to do in pandas for the result i expect.

```
A B
a r
b m
c f
```

Tried:

```
df['C']=df['A'] - df['A'].shift(-1)
```

Output Expected:

```
C
(b-a)
(c-b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df['C'] = df['A'] - df['A'].shift()
```

Or:

```
df['C'] = df['A'].diff()
```

---

Then if need remove first row with missing value:

```
df = df.iloc[1:]
```

Or if only one `NaN`s in first row:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['A'])
```

---

Like `MStaino` commented, if need shif rows up after difference (get last NaN value in `C` column):

```
df['C'] = df['A'].diff().shift(-1)
```

Comment: Nice: I would add to the second option `df['C'] = df['A'].diff().shift(-1)` if OP wants to keep dimension

Comment: But what if it were a timestamp value for example 1547986549 and 1547986666?  I would do (row2-row1/60) in excel.

Comment: @keerthana - Can you change your question with data from question? And add expected output?